# How to choose a specific record in a duplicate record query

Tags: duplicates

In my `MS Access` database, some of my data have the same `Date`, `Time` and `StationID` but have a different value in the last field (`Communication` field)

MS ACCESS DATABASE[image: 1]

How can I choose a specific record with "`VHF`" in Communication field?

I try to use `SELECT DISTINCT`, but it removed the `communication` field from my query.

Answer (score 0):

The DISTINCT function will return all rows with unique values in a specific column. What you are looking for is the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Communication = 'VHF'
```

The above will return only records with VHF in Communications.

Comment: Then how can i add Records with "GSM" only data in communication, without "VHF" duplicate, thank you sir

Comment: To clarify; Are you wanting to select rows with GSM communication if there is no VHF with similar data?

Comment: yes sir, if there is similar data (vhf and gsm), the data to choose is vhf, but if there is no similar data, just copy the record, is that posible in ms access database?